# Installing matplotlib for Python 3.5 on mac for dummies

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

How do I download and install matplotlib for Python 3.5 for my mac to use in Eclipse?  My mac is running macOS High Sierra version 10.13.1.  I can handle quantum mechanics and thermodynamics, but the whole downloading and installing and using new python programs/packages/libraries/stuff is so hopelessly confusing to me.  Assume I don't know anything, because I don't.

Comment: I assume, you already tried to open a terminal and typed in `python3 -mpip install matplotlib` and it didn't work? See here: https://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html

Answer (score 1):

For scientific work using Python I recommend using Anaconda. It has all relevant packages installed. 
[Follow these steps:](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/macos.html)

1. [Download Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/)
2. Double Click the File in your Download Folder

For further setup with Eclipse, [follow these steps.](https://github.com/mikec964/chelmbigstock/wiki/Set-up-Eclipse-(PyDev)-to-use-Anaconda-with-Python-2.7-and-3.x)

Given that you have Python3 already installed you could also try:

```
python3 -m pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: So I just did all of that, but I'm still getting the error "No module named 'matplotlib'".  What do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it is wise to consider installing a package manager like Anaconda. For something like matplotlib however, using 
 **pip install matplotlib** should be more than sufficient. For your information, the Mac already has pip (a package management system) installed, so running the above command should be enough.